# github bitcoin/doc/tor.md - Automatically versus Manually creating a Bitcoin Core tor onion service

Tags: bitcoin-core, tor, bitcoin.conf

The doc I'm asking about: [TOR SUPPORT IN BITCOIN](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/tor.md). Section 1 describes how to "Run Bitcoin Core behind a Tor proxy." Then...

2. Automatically create a Bitcoin Core onion service

---

> [I]f Tor is running and proper authentication has been configured,
> Bitcoin Core automatically creates an onion service to listen on.

This section describes how to establish proper authentication.

3. Manually create a Bitcoin Core onion service

---

> You can also manually configure your node to be reachable from the Tor
> network. Add these lines to your /etc/tor/torrc (or equivalent config
> file):
> `HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/bitcoin-service`
> `HiddenServicePort 8333 127.0.0.1:8334`

This section then describes the `externalip`, `listen`, and `discover` command line or bitcoin.conf options.

I am confused about the relation of sections 2 and 3. Are they *alternatives* or is 3 additive to 2? If the user, per section 3, adds the HiddenService... lines to torrc, and includes `externalip=[user's public 64-char code].onion` and `listen=1` in bitcoin.conf, can the authentication steps of section 2 be omitted? The `externalip` with the user's onion address of section 3 seems to provide advertising of the node's reachable tor address. But if it's omitted, how do inbound peers contact the onion service that, per section 2, is being "listen[ed] on"?

Comment: Yes 2 and 3 are alternatives.

Comment: @Prayank, what are the differences in the effect of creating (§ 2) "an onion service to listen on" and (§ 3) configuring "your node to be reachable from the Tor network"? Am I wrong in thinking that § 3 also creates an onion service to listen on?  So if they're alternatives what would motivate choosing one or the other?